# JavaFX getText(), setText(), toString() give Null Pointers

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

**Controller.java**

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller {

    public TextField txtField;
    public PasswordField passField;
    public Button btn;
    public Label access;

    private String USNM = "crimsoncoder";
    private String PASS = "toor";
```

▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬**The Issue Starts Here**▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬

```
    private String usnm = txtField.getText();
    private String pass = passField.getText();
    private String acc = access.getText();

    private final String ACCESS_GRANTED = "/ACCESS_GRANTED/";
    private final String ACCESS_DENIED = "|/?ACCESS_DENIED?/|";

    public void onClick() {
        if (usnm.equals(USNM)) {
            if (pass.equals(PASS)) {
                acc = ACCESS_GRANTED;
            } else {
                acc = ACCESS_DENIED;
            }
        } else {
            acc = ACCESS_DENIED;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the methods `getText()`,`setText()` and `toString()` after declaring the `usnm`, `pass` and `acc` variables within Controller.java returns `NullPointerException`. Any idea why this is happening?

---

New Code:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtField;
    @FXML
    private PasswordField passField;
    @FXML
    private Button btn;
    @FXML
    private Label access;

    private String USNM = "crimsoncoder";
    private String PASS = "toor";

    private static final String ACCESS_GRANTED = "/ACCESS_GRANTED/";
    private static final String ACCESS_DENIED = "|/?ACCESS_DENIED?/|";

    public void onClick() {
        String usnm = txtField.getText();
        String pass = passField.getText();

        if (usnm.equals(USNM)) {
            if (pass.equals(PASS)) {
                access.setText(ACCESS_GRANTED);
            } else {
                access.setText(ACCESS_DENIED);
            }
        } else {
            access.setText(ACCESS_DENIED);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Annotate your controls with @FXML in the controller. For e.g. `@FXML TextField txtField;`

Comment: This won't help, since a) the fields are `public` and therefore eligible for injection and b) This won't result in the fields being injected before the initializer runs. The OP needs to retrieve the value from the fields in the event handler. Also it's preferable to use `onAction` instead of `onMouseClicked`... Furthermore the handler method won't have any effect, since the `acc` field is never read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually quite a few issues with your design here. First of all, you are trying to access the values of the `txtField` and `passField` controls before those controls actually exist in the scene.

With JavaFX and FXML, those controls are not built (or injected) and available to the controller until the scene has been initialized.

The control references should also be `private` and annotated with the `@FXML` keyword, like so:

```
@FXML
private TextField txtField;
```

This essentially tells Java that the `TextField` has already been defined in the associated FXML document.

And you need to get the values of the username and password fields *after* the `LOGIN` button has been clicked, so update your `onClick()` method to retrieve the values at that time:

```
public void onClick() {

        String usnm = txtField.getText();
        String pass = passField.getText();

        String acc;

        if (usnm.equals(USNM)) {
            if (pass.equals(PASS)) {
                acc = ACCESS_GRANTED;
            } else {
                acc = ACCESS_DENIED;
            }
        } else {
            acc = ACCESS_DENIED;
        }

        System.out.println(acc);
    }
```

So, for a slightly better `Controller.java`, you could use something like this:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    public TextField txtField;
    @FXML
    public PasswordField passField;
    @FXML
    public Button btn;
    @FXML
    public Label access;

    private String USNM = "crimsoncoder";
    private String PASS = "toor";

    private static final String ACCESS_GRANTED = "/ACCESS_GRANTED/";
    private static final String ACCESS_DENIED = "|/?ACCESS_DENIED?/|";

    public void onClick() {

        String usnm = txtField.getText();
        String pass = passField.getText();

        String acc;

        if (usnm.equals(USNM)) {
            if (pass.equals(PASS)) {
                acc = ACCESS_GRANTED;
            } else {
                acc = ACCESS_DENIED;
            }
        } else {
            acc = ACCESS_DENIED;
        }

        System.out.println(acc);
    }

}
```

Comment: You do not need a `@FXML` annotation on a public field (though really the fields should be private...)

Comment: Oh, good catch. I'll update them to private as I never use public for those.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not use instance variables, rather local variable.
In other words rewrite your method in such manner:

```
public void onClick(){
        String usnm = txtField.getText();
        String pass = passField.getText();
        ...
}
```

Hope this will help.

P.S. Looks like `ACCESS_GRANTED` and `ACCESS_DENIED` should be constants, so add static identifier for them.

Answer (score 0):

it's because when class controller init, it's tray to init instance variable from another instance variable, which is null. My proposition it's move this

```
private String usnm = txtField.getText();
private String pass = passField.getText();
private String acc = access.getText();
```

to method which triggered when somebody fill this fields, and let create instance variable null.

ex.

```
private String usnm 
private String pass
private String acc
```

But:

i see you try to do this like MVC - i'm think you doing this wrong - read something about this pattern.